# jquery css issue in IE7,IE6

Tags: jquery

[my site](http://qa.ukatn.com/103/website/ta/feedback/feedback-form.php?fid=1&rno=TA20020)

```
var numStars = 15;
function change_star_image(question_id,star_id){
var count_star_rating = 0;
for (var i=1;i<numStars+1;i++){
     if(i<=star_id){count_star_rating += 1;
          $("#"+question_id+"_star_rating_image_"+i).css('background', 'url(images/full-star.gif) no-repeat 0 0');
          $("#"+question_id+"_star_rating_image_"+i).css('width', '20px');
          $("#"+question_id+"_star_rating_image_"+i).css('height', '19px');
     }else{
          $("#"+question_id+"_star_rating_image_"+i).css('background', 'url(images/empty-star.gif)no-repeat 0 0');
          $("#"+question_id+"_star_rating_image_"+i).css('width', '20px');
          $("#"+question_id+"_star_rating_image_"+i).css('height', '19px');
     }

}

document.getElementById(question_id+"_user_star_rating").value = count_star_rating; }
```

Functionality is ,

Question and answer type, answer are rating type,

user just select the star,

The prob is in IE7 and IE5, when user over to star , the star's going to hide mode,

Please tell , when i have to do now

Working Fine in FF,IE8,

But stars not working in IE6,IE7 ,

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

I think to support IE 6 and IE 7 you will have to set an image behind the star of what you want it to look like when you hover. I know that was the trick to get tab hover to work right.

Comment: Behind means , 
start back another image,